# AtTask: How to retrieve timeZone IDs

Tags: attask

I am trying to post some users from an external system onto workfront. I would like to post a timeZone  value to a user through api. How do I get the timeZone ID so that I can pass it to the put users rest api.

Thank You,
Uma

Comment: It depends how do you keep the user's timezone information in your external system.

Answer (score 0):

The Timezone Value is a String, I can't confirm if it is from a Java class based on your locale.

While somewhat labor intensive, you could switch your timezone and use

**/api/user/search?ID={ID}&fields=timeZone** to retrieve the values that correspond with the drop down on the User Profile GUI.

If you already have users set to all the Timezones that you use, generate a User Report with the Timezone column to get the values.

Answer (score 0):

The format for timezones can be found here.
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-date-time/java-util-timezone.html
we don't use all in the list but the format for the ones in the drop down within the application should work.